# Cross compile platforms

Tags: android, scala, sbt, cross-platform

I wanted to create sbt cross platforms (Hello world app ) including JVM , Scala Native , Android and scalajs , I have succeed in compiling all of them except the android and this is my build.sbt:

```
name := "Cross-Platforms-ScalaNative-JVM"

import sbtcrossproject.CrossPlugin.autoImport.{crossProject, CrossType}

val sharedSettings = Seq(scalaVersion := "2.11.12")

lazy val bar =
// select supported platforms
  crossProject(JSPlatform, JVMPlatform, NativePlatform)
    .crossType(CrossType.Full)
    .settings(sharedSettings)
    .jsSettings(
      libraryDependencies += "org.querki" %%% "jquery-facade" % "1.2") 
    .jvmSettings(/* ... */)
    .nativeSettings(/* ... */)

lazy val barJS     = bar.js
lazy val barJVM    = bar.jvm
lazy val barNative = bar.native
```

[image: This is how my project looks]

My question how I can create an android platform in this project; what changes should be to my SBT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android build is basically an JVM build with an extra steps - taking JVM bytecode, optionally running proguard to minimize code and compiling it into Android format.

Here you have a lot of information about how to setup normal android build in sbt: https://scala-android.org/quickstart/.

The difference would be by applying `androidBuild` (and all Android-related settings) only to JVM projects:

```scala
val myProjectJVM = myProject.jvm
  .settings(androidBuild: _*)
```

However, considering that Android build and normal Scala build will look differently (as normal JVM application has architecturally little to do with Android apps - e.g. `Main.main(Array[String])` vs Android fragments and services) it would be a better idea to have a module for some shared JVM code and a dedicated projects for the platform-specific parts:

```scala
val commonJVM = myProject.jvm
val myProjectJVM = project.in(file("java-specific"))
  .dependsOn(commonJVM)
val myProjectAndroid = project.in(file("android-specific"))
  .settings(androidBuild)
  .dependsOn(commonJVM)
```

That architectural difference is most likely a reason why nobody even considers making Android a fourth option in a cross project - you have a different runtime dependencies, a different way to start the application, so you would have more parts of the code that differ than in common. Submodules with code dedicated to platform depending on common dependency (even cross-compiled one) is a better idea.